# jQuery datatables plugin databinding with string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I'm getting a JSON response from my service. Following the tutorial, I created response for binding data in datatables jquery plugin.

**Client Side code :**

```
var test_reports = jsonResp.reports;
var aDataSet = [test_reports];

$('#example').dataTable( {
    "aaData": aDataSet,
    "aoColumns": [{ "sTitle": "Tests" },
          { "sTitle": "Reports"}]
});
```

In console, my "test_reports" shows :

```
['TEST_1','1'] ['TEST_2','1']
```

But while binding this data to tables, it throws error. If I copy this cosole output into aaData, it creates the table. I understood that my "test_reports" is a string and this plugin is expecting an array of values. Any ideas of making this work!!

**Server side code** which gives this json response :

```
testcasesCountRS = statement.executeQuery(testcasesQuery);

            while(testcasesCountRS.next()){
                String test_name = testcasesCountRS.getString("test_name");
                String test_count = testcasesCountRS.getString("test_count");
                testResults.put(test_name, test_count);
                resBuffer.append("[\'" + test_name + "\',\'" + test_count + "\'],");
            }

resBuffer = resBuffer.deleteCharAt(resBuffer.lastIndexOf(","));

reports.put("reports", resBuffer);
```

Is there any alternative in my server side code to send the response as an array object to the datatables plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You server response should be an array of array.

`[['TEST_1','1'],['TEST_2','1']]`

Change your code to

```
resBuffer.append("[");
while(testcasesCountRS.next()){
    String test_name = testcasesCountRS.getString("test_name");
    String test_count = testcasesCountRS.getString("test_count");
    testResults.put(test_name, test_count);
    resBuffer.append("[\'" + test_name + "\',\'" + test_count + "\'],");
}
resBuffer = resBuffer.deleteCharAt(resBuffer.lastIndexOf(","));
resBuffer.append("]");
```

The above code is untested. But hope you get the idea.

[Documentation link](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer bhb. Problem here is when I use this in a String context, it sends the response as a String itself. But I'm supposed to use JSONArray and send the response.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work the following way :

```
JSONArray testCaseArray = new JSONArray();
while(testcasesCountRS.next()){
                JSONArray testCase = new JSONArray();
                String test_name = testcasesCountRS.getString("test_name");
                String test_count = testcasesCountRS.getString("test_count");

                testCase.add(test_name);
                testCase.add(test_count);
                testCaseArray.add(testCase);
}

reports.put("reports", testCaseArray);
```

The only thing thats bothering me is, it so stupid code that I need to create a new Array every time in my loop. And adding these arrays to my main Array object. There should be some work around to make it simple. Please suggest some efficient methodology.